# Problem with referencing plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys

I want to reference some plots (done with pgfplots) in my text but somehow it's not possible.

If i copypaste the examples from the pgfplot- documentation it works but if I move one of the labels to my plot it breaks while compiling the 2nd time (as long as the reference is rendered as "??" it's fine).

This is the error I get:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/plot' and I am going to i
gnore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.105 Here the legend image \ref{pgfplots:plot2}
                                                 is displayed correctly.
? 
Der Prozess wurde vom Benutzer abgebrochen
```

Referencing of the same plot in the legend works by the way.

```
   \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[plot/.style={very thick,raw gnuplot,mark=none,black}]
 \begin{axis}[
 legend cell align=left, minor y tick num=3, minor x tick num=1, width=0.5\textwidth, domain=-pi/2:pi/2,
 ymin=0, ymax=1.3, xmin=-1.571, xmax=1.571, grid=both, y=5cm, axis y line=left, axis x line=bottom]
 \addplot gnuplot [plot,red]
     { ag1(x) = 0.33*sin(x);plot[-pi/2:pi/2]ag1(x)};
     \label{pgfplots:label4}
     \addlegendentry{$\delta_1=10 \ref{pgfplots:label3}$};
 \addplot gnuplot [plot,green]
     {ag1(x) =  0.33*cos(x);plot[-pi/2:pi/2]ag1(x)};
     \label{pgfplots:label3}
     \addlegendentry{$\delta_1=10 \ref{pgfplots:label4}$};
 \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture} \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline] \begin{axis}
 \addplot+ {3*x+2.5*rand};
     \label{pgfplots:label1}
 \addplot+[mark=none] {3*x};
     \label{pgfplots:label2}
 \addplot {4*cos(deg(x))};
    % \label{pgfplots:label3} %IF THIS LINE ISN'T A COMMENT IT WORKS
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \section{References}
 \ref{pgfplots:label1}\\
 \ref{pgfplots:label2}\\
% \ref{pgfplots:label3}\\
 \end{document}
```

So i have two pictures - if the label3 is in the lower picture it works, if it's in the other picture it doesn't compile.

Comment: Can you please add to your question a minimal, *complete* document illustrating the problem?

Comment: I guess you put `\label` and/or `\ref` into the wrong line, but without seeing the code one can not tell.

Comment: added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are referring the plot labelled `pgfplots:label3` outside the plot and this was produced with the `plot` style, you need to declare this style globally; otherwise, having it only locally as in your code, the style isn't known outside the plot when the reference occurs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\tikzset{
plot/.style={very thick,raw gnuplot,mark=none,black}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
legend cell align=left,
minor y tick num=3,
minor x tick num=1,
width=0.5\textwidth,
domain=-pi/2:pi/2,
ymin=0,
ymax=1.3,
xmin=-1.57079632679,
xmax=1.57079632679,
grid=both,
y=5cm,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=bottom,
xlabel={$\varphi [^\circ]$},
ylabel=$a^{(c)}$]
\addplot gnuplot [plot,dashdotted]{
ag0(x) =    +0.330477   -2.06663*(x/pi)**2  +2.90481*(x/pi)**4  +0.296334*(x/pi)**6;
ag1(x) =    -0.398712   +3.35323*(x/pi)**2  -8.06845*(x/pi)**4  +4.13977*(x/pi)**6;
ag2(x) =    -0.1077     -0.990205*(x/pi)**2 +8.82304*(x/pi)**4  -12.5561*(x/pi)**6;
ag3(x) =    +0.226138   -0.545837*(x/pi)**2 -3.58968*(x/pi)**4  +8.61929*(x/pi)**6;
ag(x,y)=    ag0(x)+(log(y)/6)*(ag1(x)+(log(y)/6)*(ag2(x)+(log(y)/6)*(ag3(x))));
plot[-pi/2:pi/2]ag(x,100);
};
\label{pgfplots:label3}
\addlegendentry{$\delta_1=10 $\ref{pgfplots:label3}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[only marks,
samples=15,
error bars/y dir=both,
error bars/y fixed=2.5]
{3*x+2.5*rand};
\label{pgfplots:label1}
\addplot+[mark=none] {3*x};
\label{pgfplots:label2}
\addplot {4*cos(deg(x))};
%\label{pgfplots:label3} %NOW IT WORKS
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{References}

\ref{pgfplots:label1}\\
\ref{pgfplots:label2}\\
\ref{pgfplots:label3}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]